# Need assistance with WHERE rlike and between for search code

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys can u point me my mistake :( i want to make multi-column search for my page:
So my script its this:

```
<?
$search=$_GET['s'];

$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` WHERE `nomer` rlike '$search' or `rezume` rlike '$search' or `kategoriq` rlike '$search' or ' order by seriq asc ";
?>
```

want to make to search by price-range so i create this:

```
<?
$search=$_GET['s'];
$pricemin=$_GET['min'];
$pricemax=$_GET['max'];
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` WHERE `nomer` rlike '$search' or `rezume` rlike '$search' or `kategoriq` rlike '$search' or 'seriq' BETWEEN '$pricemin' and '$pricemax'  order by seriq asc ";
?>
```

how to replace between it this case ? i watch some others people code for search engines and they use `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE Table1 LIKE '%$table1%' AND Table2 LIKE '%$table2%' AND  Price BETWEEN '%$min%','%$max%'");`
but its doesnt work with mine ;( pls help

Comment: Your first mistake is you aren't using prepared statements and have SQL injection holes. Use PDO here is a [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: hmm this is not my whole code. i just need help with the $query :( how to use between in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` to filter your result set by the price range like this

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` 
         WHERE (`nomer` RLIKE '$search' OR 
                `rezume` RLIKE '$search' OR 
                `kategoriq` RLIKE '$search') AND 
                `seriq` BETWEEN '$pricemin' AND '$pricemax'  
         ORDER BY seriq";
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5eda/2)

And as @cryptic suggested consider using prepared statements either with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

**UPDATE3:** And this is how you can use prepared statement in your case with `mysqli` and make it possible to search by keyword only, by keyword and price range or only by price range:

```
$stype = 0;
if (isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']){
    $search=$_GET['s'];
    $stype += 1;
}
if (isset($_GET['min']) && $_GET['min'] && 
    isset($_GET['max']) && $_GET['max']){
    $pricemin=$_GET['min'];
    $pricemax=$_GET['max'];
    $stype +=2;
}
if (!$stype) {
    echo "Required parameter(s) missing.";
    exit;
}
/* connect to the database*/
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");
/* check connection */
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` WHERE ";
if ($stype == 1) {
    $query .= " (`nomer` rlike ? OR `rezume` rlike ? OR `kategoriq` rlike ?) ";
} elseif ($stype == 2) {
    $query .= " `seriq` BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
} elseif ($stype == 3) {
    $query .= " (`nomer` rlike ? OR `rezume` rlike ? OR `kategoriq` rlike ?) AND `seriq` BETWEEN ? AND ?";
}
$query .= " ORDER BY seriq";
/* create a prepared statement */
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($query)) {
    //handle error here;
    echo "Error preparing statement.";
    exit;
}
/* bind parameters for markers */
if ($stype == 1) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $search, $search, $search);
} elseif ($stype == 2) {
    $stmt->bind_param("dd", $pricemin, $pricemax);
} elseif ($stype == 3) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssdd", $search, $search, $search, $pricemin, $pricemax);
}
/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
/* get result */
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result) {
/* now you can fetch the results into an assoc array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['nomer']. ", " .$row['rezume']. ", " .$row['kategoriq']. ", " .$row['seriq']. "<br>";
    }
}
/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
/* close db connection */
$db->close();
```

Comment: Hello your code works great but its required all the $value be fill ;\ i mean i cant search only by $search or $pricemin / $pricemax.

Comment: To do that you just need to construct query dynamically and bind appropriate parameters. See updated answer for example. And let me know if it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: I am glad you answer , thank you i try this variant but it doesn't show me only price range 

} elseif ($stype == 2) {
    $query .= " seriq BETWEEN '$pricemin AND '$pricemax "; '``

Comment: Well, with this script to search only by a keyword your url parameters should be `script.php?s=keyword`, to search only by price range `script.php?min=10&max=40`, to search by both `script.php?s=keyword&min=10&max=40`. This is just an example. You can implement any other logic.

Comment: yes but when i click the search button it show it all script.php?s=&min=&max= my <form> is simple ` <input type="text"  name="s" value="" size="24" border="0"> `and `<p>price min: <select name="min" type="hidden" size="1">

and when i submit it the url is: `search.php?s=varna&min=10000&max=30000&Submit=Search `

Comment: Why when its empty its show's all the tags i men when i just wrire the URL: search.php?s=keyword its show me the key word when i just put script.php?min=10&max=40 its good again but why it show me all tags search.php?s=keyword&min=&max= ... :(

Comment: Tweak the logic of the script for your needs. For that particular case see once again updated answer. Now you can do this `script.php?s=varna&min=&max=` and this `script.php?s=&min=10000&max=30000`

Comment: you are brilliant! Thank you for your time! I owe you a lot , and sorry for bother you with this but i really want finish this project for my parents. once again thank you.

Comment: Need your assistance again ;( i am trying to put some pagination for the search.
I put 

`$pages = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$pp = "2"; 
$pages = ceil($pages/$pp);
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){$page = 1;}else{$page = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_GET['page']));}
$limit = ( $pp * $page ) - $pp;`

and

 `$query .= " ORDER BY seriq asc LIMIT $limit,$pp";` 

 
But have problem with the buttons NEXT AND PREVIOUS :(
 now the code works when i type 
`script.php?s=&min=10000&max=30000?page=5` 
but cant make the actual buttons

Comment: @user2052643 It's a perfect candidate for another question. Post it with relevant code or better yet make a link from a new question to this one and other members of community or I will be more than happy to help you with that.

Comment: will be glad if you help me again
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989030/pagination-for-search-script

Answer (score 0):

The query (disregarding SQL injection):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE field1 LIKE '%$table1%' 
AND field2 LIKE '%$table2%' 
AND Price BETWEEN 'val3' AND 'val2'
```

You cannot use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) to do `like` comparison.